# Read curl php result

Tags: php

I'm doing a curl and getting the JSON result as:

```
$data = json_decode($result, true);
var_dump($data);
$data = $data["data"];
echo $data;
```

However, the echo of $data is "{". If I do a var_dump before assigning again the variable I see:

```
string(727796) "{"data":["base64_image1", "base64_image2",... ]}"
```

Why am I not able to access the data list? I just want to do a foreach over this list, but I cannot.

Comment: output is json so try to json_decode() again

Comment: Nice! It works! Write your comment as an answer and I will accept it

Comment: It would probably be better to fix the server code so it doesn't encode twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

output is json so try to json_decode() again